# Why does CH3CH(OH)CH2CH3 give iodoform test?

Tags: organic-chemistry

The iodoform test is given by compounds containing $\ce{-(C=O)CH3}$ group or compounds which can be oxidized to such. 
$$\ce{ CH3CH(OH)CH2CH3}$$

Is a 2 degree alchohol and even though it were to be oxidized it would not contain a $\ce{-(C=O)CH3}$ group but according to a question asked by JEE in 1997 it as a matter of fact does give the test.

**HOW?**

Comment: This alcohol can be oxidised to a ketone as $\ce{I2/NaOH}$ is also an oxidising agent (as it produces $\ce{NaOI}$ in which iodine is at higher oxidation number than general).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The substrate you have provided (2-butanol) would indeed give a positive test.

The iodoform test is performed in presence of iodine and potassium or sodium hydroxide, which first oxidizes the aforesaid compound to 2-Butanone.

**Mechanism** (taken from [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haloform_reaction#Mechanism)) which shows $\ce{BrO-}$ instead of $\ce{IO-}$, but would be executed in a similar fashion:

[image: Mechanism of secondary alcohol to ketone by the hypohalite ion]

Thus 2-Butanone responds to iodoform test successfully.

---

**References:**

[Ueber Entstehung von Jodoform und Anwendung dieser Reaction in der chemischen Analyse, Lieben, *Ann. Spl. Bd.* 7, 218 **1870**](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uiug.30112018225695&view=1up&seq=230)