# Do alpha hydroxy ketones give iodoform test

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, tautomer

So, we know that alpha hydroxy ketones give tollens test as the tautomerise into their enol form and the then have an equilibrium between the 2 keto forms.

So going ahead with the same logic. Do alpha hydroxy ketones which can tautomerise to give a methyl ketone group, can they give positive iodoform test?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/73313/why-do-%ce%b1-hydroxy-ketones-give-tollens-test https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/94620/in-what-way-could-benzoin-give-tollens-test

Comment: Huh, I misunderstood your question. Your parallel isn't good. It's rather a duplicate of https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/104242/why-does-ch3chohch2ch3-give-iodoform-test

Comment: Depends on the structure of the alpha hydroxy ketone. Oxidation of an alpha hydroxy ketone to an alpha diketone is not the same as an iodoform test.